# How to change backgroundImage dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a data on my hits array and I want to foreach them.

```js
<Paper style={{backgroundImage:'url(${hit.profile_banner_url})'}}  className={classes.paper}>
```

It's not working. How Can I change backgroundImage on each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `` instead of '

like below

```
<Paper style={{backgroundImage:`url(${hit.profile_banner_url})`}}  className={classes.paper}>
```

Comment: @AlperenARICI Your Welcome, You Can Mark it as answer to help others use this

Comment: Stackoverflow said "You can accept an answer in 12 minutes" :)

Comment: Ok ; No Problem : - ) @AlperenARICI